# Can anyone help correct my method for going backwards in time?

Tags: java

here is the code I found that allows a method to go forward in time, but I am confused on how to make it go backwards.

```
    while (true) {            
        if (++min == 60) {
            min = 0;
            ++hour;
            hour %= 24;
        }
```

Comment: (Assuming I understand the problem statement) to start with, you can check if all digits are the same, as in your 22:22 example. If so, you can just return the same time.

Comment: Can you share what the output is, and how it differs from what you expect?

Comment: As far as I see, you are looking ahead of the current time and not backwards. This wont give you the result you want. I am looking at your problem more intense now.

Answer (score 2):

The bug in your code is that you are going *forward* in time, instead of going *backward*.

The part that needs to be changed is:

```
while (true) {
    if (--min < 0) {
        min = 59;
        if (--hour < 0) {
            hour = 23;
        }
    }
```

Note that I avoided to use the `%` operator with negative numbers. That's because I just cannot remember whether `-1 % 24` is either `-1` or `+23`. Since [programming languages differ in the result](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation), I usually only use the `%` operator when both sides are positive numbers.

The rest of the code looks straightforward and solves the task nicely.

The task in itself is a bit unrealistic, but that's not your fault. It's still a good exercise.